# AWS Lambda function Key Error with trigger on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Basic lambda function trying to get contents of the bucket but getting errors though

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3

print('Loading function')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        print("CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])
        return response['ContentType']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

Here is the error message when i run the lambda function.

Error message

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'Records'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "requestId": "5c89bb8e-a70e-4c33-ba00-43174095544e",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 13, in lambda_handler\n    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']\n"
  ]
}
```

Function Logs

```
START RequestId: 5c89bb8e-a70e-4c33-ba00-43174095544e Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] KeyError: 'Records'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 13, in lambda_handler
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
END RequestId: 5c89bb8e-a70e-4c33-ba00-43174095544e
REPORT RequestId: 5c89bb8e-a70e-4c33-ba00-43174095544e  Duration: 1.89 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 69 MB  Init Duration: 356.28 ms
```

Comment: You code already contains a line to print the event. How does the event look like? The error states that there is no key `Records` . So that's the problem. The event you do receive does not contain a `Records` key. Please share the events JSON that you are receiving.

Comment: How is this Lambda function being invoked? Are you invoking it via the Lambda management console? If so, did you provide it with a Test Event using the `S3` template? Or are you triggering the function from Amazon S3?

Comment: I tried to invoke lambda from lambda console and getting triggered when S3 receive new update and as well as codepipeline is getting triggered. I understand there is no key records but why? I'm manually dropping file to S3, that's triggering lambda function with above left.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
```

Doesn't exist. Check the event object when its been triggered from S3. If you want to test in console you need to pass a similarly shaped object as the event.